# Verify that $\lim_{h\to0} (1+hx)^{1/h} = e^x$

Tags: limits, exponential-function, definition, limits-without-lhopital

**Question :** Verify the limit:
$$\lim_{h\to0} (1+hx)^{1/h} = e^x$$

**Background :** I don't even know where to start with this. I am in Calculus-I (at the point in the course where we are on L'Hopitals rule), and I believe that my professor means for me to use the Delta/Sigma definition learned earlier in the semester, although I have no clue. I really stuck here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: some take it as the definition of $e^x$. In that case, there is nothing to verify. So before we can answer we need to know: what is _your_ definition?

Comment: I am in Calculus 1 (at the point in the course where we are on L'Hopitals rule), and I believe that my professor means for me to use the Delta/Sigma definition learned earlier in the semester, although I have no clue. I really feel kinda stuck here

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{h\to0} (1+hx)^{1/h} &= \exp\left(\lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\log(1+hx)\right)\\&=\exp\left(\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x}{1+hx}\right)\\&=\exp(x)\end{align}$$
From the first line to the second, we used L'hopital's rule.